# "Dependent optional" data in Haskell

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

Consider a DateTime type where the date must be present, but the time part in seconds is optional. If the time part is there, there might be an optional milliseconds part, too. If milliseconds are present, there might be a nanoseconds part, too.

There are many ways to deal with this, e.g.:

```
--rely on smart constructors 
data DateTime = DateTime { days:: Int, 
                           sec :: Maybe Int, 
                           ms :: Maybe Int, 
                           ns :: Maybe Int 
                         }

-- list all possibilities
data DateTime = DateOnly Int 
              | DateWithSec Int Int
              | DateWithMilliSec Int Int Int
              | DateWithNanoSec Int Int Int Int    

-- cascaded Maybe
data DateTime = DateTime Int (Maybe (Int, Maybe (Int, Maybe Int)))

-- cascaded data
data Nano = NoNano | Nano Int
data MilliSec = NoMilliSec | MilliSec Int Nano
data Sec = NoSec | Sec Int MilliSec
data Date = Date Int Sec
```

Which construct would you use (of course not limited to the examples above), and why?

**[Intentions]**

I'm exploring the possibilities for a date type in Frege ( http://code.google.com/p/frege/ ), using date4j's `DateTime` as a guide line (as Haskell's date and time lib is way too complicated, and `java.util.Date` too broken). In my current toy implementation all fields are mandatory, but of course it would be nice to free the user from unwanted precision (and the original implementation *has* optional fields).

So the main goals are:

- safety: Illegal states must be avoided at all costs
- convenience: It should be easy to work with the type, e.g. pattern matching would be cool, calendar calculations should be easy...

Not so important are:

- performance: Of course working with the type shouldn't be too slow, but for the typical usage it doesn't have to sqeeze out the last clock cycle
- memory: In cases where this really matters, it would be easy to derive a more compact storage format
- terse implementation: It's a library, and I'm willing to add all the code needed to make things smooth

That said, all of this is very tentative and shouldn't be taken too serious.

Comment: Not sure this is answerable without knowing more about your requirements. It can depend on many things, including what functions you plan on defining on the type, performance and space considerations (number of indirections, opportunities for unpacking fields, etc.)

Comment: Another option is to use a simple constructor `DateTime = DateTime [Int]` which isn't exported from the library, and force all interaction with the type to be through functions like `mkDateTimeWithSec :: [Int] -> DateTime`, `isDateTimeWithSec :: DateTime -> Bool`, `getSeconds :: DateTime -> Maybe Int` etc. You can't use pattern matching (but maybe that's not terrible, as you just replace it with guards and use the accessor functions) but you explicitly disallow your users from creating illegal states, as you can check everything at construction time (e.g. you can check for negative values).

Comment: The original assertion that unspecified data is optional rather than default makes for a very contrived type - writing functions to manipulate it will be tedious. You can also have junk like a value with Just nanoseconds but Nothing seconds. I'd change tack and work out whether defaulting to 0 for unspecified time values is detrimental in theory and practice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(This isn't an answer, but it's too long for a comment and will be clearer here.)

There is another way that you could handle it: have a single `DateTime` type that stores all fields always along with a parameter representing the precision, e.g.

```
data Precision = Days | Seconds | Milliseconds | Nanoseconds deriving (Ord, Eq {- etc -})
data DateTime = DateTime { prec :: Precision,
                           days :: Int, 
                           sec :: Int,
                           ms :: Int,
                           ns :: Int }
```

And use smart constructors that set the unused parameters to `0`. If you have `dateDifference` or whatever, you can propagate the precision through (the `Ord` instance would make this neat).

(I've got little idea about how good/Haskell-y this is, but the other solutions seem quite messy, maybe this is more elegant.)

Comment: I was about to suggest this kind of solution myself.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I would have suggested, but I also would have suggested just collapsing the `sec`, `ms`, and `ns` fields into a single `withinDay` field whose interpretation would be as seconds, milliseconds, or nanoseconds depending on the value of the `prec` field.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I don't think that would work, not without changing datatypes: (for a 32 bit platform) the maximum value of an `Int` is a few billion, but there are 86 trillion nanoseconds in a day.

Answer (score 8):

“Illegal states must be avoided at all costs” and “pattern matching would be cool” are fine principles that in this case are in direct conflict with each other.

In addition, dates and times are gnarly human cultural constructs with lots of edge cases and irregular corners. They are not the sort of rules we can easily encode in the type system.

So in this case I would go with an opaque data type, smart constructors, and smart deconstructors. There's always view patterns and pattern guards for occasions when we want to use pattern matching.

(And I haven't even discussed dependent optional data as a motivating factor.)

Comment: View patterns would be very useful here, but are currently not supported in my target language Frege (which is otherwise very similar to Haskell)

Comment: That's unfortunate. I think I would go this way regardless, and hope Frege supported view patterns in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @dbaupp's solution I'd like to add a phantom type version to the candidates:

```
-- using EmptyDataDecls
data DayPrec 
data SecPrec 
data MilliPrec 
data NanoPrec 

data DateTime a = DateTime { days :: Int, sec :: Int, ms :: Int, ns :: Int } 

date :: Int -> DateTime DayPrec
date d = DateTime d 0 0 0

secDate :: Int -> Int -> DateTime SecPrec
secDate d s = DateTime d s 0 0

...    

--will work only for same precision which is a Good Thing (tm)
instance Eq (DateTime a) where
  (DateTime d s ms ns) == (DateTime d' s' ms' ns') = [d,s,ms,ns] == [d',s',ms',ns']
```

If I'm not mistaken, this allows me to work with one type, but to distinguish precisions if I need to. But I guess there will be some drawback as well...

Comment: I like this, except I think this would make some things a little awkward, e.g. computing the time between a `DateTime DayPrec` and `DateTime SecPrec` and getting the correct precision (presumably `DayPrec`): I think it would require something like functional dependencies or type families, or typing out a lot of instance declarations. (Assuming that such an operation is desired and well-defined.)

Comment: I think the user shouldn't mix different precisions, but instead explicitly truncate or extend the precision before calculating.

Comment: What will the type of `parseDateTime` be? (If the programmer wants to preserve the level of precision in the original string, but doesn't know at compile time how much precision to expect?)

Comment: Agreed, that would be inconvenient. However, you could have functions like `isMilliPrecision :: String -> Bool` in order to test before you actually parse, and `parseMilliPrecision :: String -> Maybe (DateTime MilliPrec)`. Note that you don't have the problem if you e.g. read dates from databases, or if you convert `java.util.Date` (which should be considered als `MilliPrec`), where you know the expected precision.

Comment: @dbaupp you would essentially have to perform a type-level `min` operation, which is not unheard of in the Haskell world.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only want to solve this problem (as opposed to a more generic one) then the [decimal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Decimal-0.2.2) library might be what you want.